# Python Twitter API using OAuth not providing email

Tags: python, django, twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to use Twitter API to allow Twitter login for my site. Using Python (Django), I have been able to get the user's name and username and other relevant data, but not the user's email.

I have already checked the box for email permission on apps.twitter.com, and the user is prompted that his/her email will be used when login in. But the request does not contain the email.

Here's my code:

```
def get_user_details(self, response):

    """Return user details from Twitter account"""
    try:
        first_name, last_name = response['name'].split(' ', 1)
    except:
        first_name = response['name']
        last_name = ''
    print response
    return {'username': response['screen_name'],
            'email': response['email'],  
            'fullname': response['name'],
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name}
```

The response that is printed contains and `screen_name` and `name`, but not the `email`. I know my tokens are correct because I get all the other data.

This is the API call I'm making:

```
TWITTER_CHECK_AUTH = 'https://%s/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true&include_entities=false&skip_status=true' % TWITTER_SERVER
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some values in the app settings. The documentation mentions that in order to retrieve the user's email address the privacy policy url and terms of service url must be provided.

`The "Request email addresses from users" checkbox is available under the app permissions on developer.twitter.com. Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields must be completed in the app settings in order for email address access to function. If enabled, users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that your app can access their email address.`

Comment: We have already checked the email box and included our Privacy Policy/Terms of Service links. Our users are being prompted that the app accesses their emails. But the emails are not appearing in the request. Are there any other settings you can think of that we might be missing?

Comment: Are you sure the user has an associated email address and that the email address is a verfified one?

Comment: Could you try after deleting existing tokens and reauthenticating the users?